# why isn't there a People.SE?

Tags: support

i "think" that there should be a website where people can ask some general social questions, i have seen many sites here which attempts to do the same but they cover a single general topic, thats why i am asking, why isnt there a Peope.Se which could cover much more juice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Over the course of launching 40+ Stack Exchange sites, it was found that the concept and engine works best when it has a clear and relatively narrow focus, and is populated by experts for that narrow focus. So things like:

- A site for [Programmers](http://stackoverflow.com)
- A site for [Gamers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)
- A site for [Physicists](http://physics.stackexchange.com)
- A site for [Mathematicians](http://math.stackexchange.com)

all seem to work because the goal is clearly defined and the potential experts are clearly defined. When you work with a concept that's broad or ill-defined (People would be that), there's no focus for the user base: it's hard to impossible to know what is a good question for the site, what is a bad question the site, who are the experts in the field, and if there are any experts, why they would choose to participate in the site.

So rather than a People.SE site, think:

- An SE for [psychologists](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3431/psychology)
- An SE for anthropologists
- An SE for sociologists
- An SE for [human resources](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2900/human-resources)

And so on.

If you're interested in learning more about the background, the Stack Exchange team has written a few different blog posts about it:

- [No Artificial Intelligence in Area 51](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/) talks about how a failed SE site, [Artificial Intelligence.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence), due to a lack of clearly-defined experts
- [Stack Overflow Around the World](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-overflow-around-the-world/) talks about the success of Stack Exchange in narrowly defined topics, and how that relates to localized communities
- [Pruning Season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) talks about another failed site, [Electronic Gadgets.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), which didn't have a clearly defined and narrow scope
- [Merging Season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) talks about what the sweet spot is for a site's scope

As a postscript, it's also interesting to look at [Atheism.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism), which failed mostly because it was an SE site for people who *are* something rather than a site for people who *do* something. That is, if you happened to be an atheist, you were automatically an expert: obviously, that's not true, and it's hard to define what an "expert" atheist would be.

The same would be true of a People.SE: who is an "expert" person?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this three or four more times.

Comment: thanks for the answer Mark, i didnt think it that way, it is really hard to describe someone socially "expert" +1 for you

Comment: Good answer, Mark. As a side-note, Skeptics is an "are" like Atheists, although you could generally say the answerers are expert "researchers".  Skeptics explicitly disallows questions *about* skepticism, which, based on your answer here, is a good move. I think it will be interesting to see if Skeptics makes it out of beta (and if so, learn what made it work).

Comment: @Renesis: I think one difference between Skeptics.SE and Atheists.SE is that sceptics *do* something (research why something isn't the case) whereas atheists *don't do* something (believe in god). It is a lot easier to rate how well something is done, rather than how well it isn't done.